# Should I prefer an explicit allocation over a non-pointer member?

Tags: c++

I have a `Console` class that I use as an internal logging facility. It could grow to thousands of string entries. I attach it to classes like this:

```
class App{
public:

    Console console;
...
```

My understanding that whether I do it this way or instead have a member that is `Console* console` (or a shared pointer variant), either way it is allocated in an static storage area and as far as memory usage goes, it would be about the same in either approach. Is this correct?

Are there any other reasons or considerations why I should prefer one or the other approach? If this was the stack memory area, I know there would be much more obvious reasons to prefer a pointer allocation for a large object, but I don't think that applies here.

Since I can get the address of this fine, if I do need a pointer, that is trivial to pass around, so I don't see the clear advantage of allocating this explicitly in this scenario. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pointer or smart pointer to the object, that means the object will be allocated from the heap.

If App has a direct Console member, then it is allocated from the same pool as the App object.

If Console stores the strings as std::strings or especially std::strings in a standard library container, then the storage does not matter very much because the string data would be dynamically allocated from the heap anyway.

So I'd recommend just having Console as a member because that is the most hassle free way, unless you have e.g. a need to change to a different Console while the App is running.